Resizebox not scaling text in tikz image
I am trying to scale the tikz image

using resizebox, but for some reason the text in the image is not being scaled:

Here is my code:
\begin{frame}{Circle Packing} \pause
\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\resizebox{5cm}{!}{
    \begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style={transform shape}]
        \draw[ultra thin] (0.0000000000in, 0.0000000000in) circle (3.0000000000in);
        \draw[ultra thin] (0.0000000000in, 1.2500000000in) circle (1.7500000000in);
        \draw[ultra thin] (-0.4941176471in, -1.6941176471in) circle (1.2352941176in);
        \draw[ultra thin] (1.6800000000in, -0.9900000000in) circle (1.0500000000in);
        \draw[thin, red] (0.4800000000in, -0.6400000000in) circle (0.2000000000in);
        \draw[thin, red] (1.0500000000in, -2.3375000000in) circle (0.4375000000in);
        \draw[thin, red] (2.2909090909in, 0.5818181818in) circle (0.6363636364in);
        \draw[thin, red] (-2.1000000000in, -0.3250000000in) circle (0.8750000000in);
        \node[align=center] at (0in, 1.25in) {\fontsize{.3475in}{0in}\selectfont 12};
        \node[align=center] at (-0.4941176471in, -1.6941176471in) {\fontsize{.3075in}{0in}\selectfont 17};
        \node[align=center] at (1.68in, -0.99in) {\fontsize{.2625in}{0in}\selectfont 20};
        \node[align=center] at (1.05in, -2.3375in) {\fontsize{0.109375in}{0in}\selectfont 48};
        \node[align=center] at (2.2909090909in, 0.5818181818in) {\fontsize{0.159075in}{0in}\selectfont 33};
        \node[align=center] at (-2.1in, -0.3250000000in) {\fontsize{0.21875in}{0in}\selectfont 24};
        \node[align=center] at (0.48in, -0.64in) {\fontsize{0.04in}{0in}\selectfont 105};
    \end{tikzpicture}}
\end{figure}
\end{frame}


Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with \documentclass{...}, the required \usepackage's, \begin{document}, and \end{document}. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for the users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Also, beamer does not have a floating mechanism, so adding [H] does not make a lot of sense and you don't need \centering, beamer centres figures my default.

XeLaTeX and TikZ are known to have certain compatibility issues.

You can forcefully scale your image by transforming the whole canvas:
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{lmodern} 

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Circle Packing} 
\begin{figure}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.2,transform canvas={scale=2}]
        \draw[ultra thin] (0.0000000000in, 0.0000000000in) circle (3.0000000000in);
        \draw[ultra thin] (0.0000000000in, 1.2500000000in) circle (1.7500000000in);
        \draw[ultra thin] (-0.4941176471in, -1.6941176471in) circle (1.2352941176in);
        \draw[ultra thin] (1.6800000000in, -0.9900000000in) circle (1.0500000000in);
        \draw[thin, red] (0.4800000000in, -0.6400000000in) circle (0.2000000000in);
        \draw[thin, red] (1.0500000000in, -2.3375000000in) circle (0.4375000000in);
        \draw[thin, red] (2.2909090909in, 0.5818181818in) circle (0.6363636364in);
        \draw[thin, red] (-2.1000000000in, -0.3250000000in) circle (0.8750000000in);
        \node[align=center] at (0in, 1.25in) {\fontsize{.3475in}{0in}\selectfont 12};
        \node[align=center] at (-0.4941176471in, -1.6941176471in) {\fontsize{.3075in}{0in}\selectfont 17};
        \node[align=center] at (1.68in, -0.99in) {\fontsize{.2625in}{0in}\selectfont 20};
        \node[align=center] at (1.05in, -2.3375in) {\fontsize{0.109375in}{0in}\selectfont 48};
        \node[align=center] at (2.2909090909in, 0.5818181818in) {\fontsize{0.159075in}{0in}\selectfont 33};
        \node[align=center] at (-2.1in, -0.3250000000in) {\fontsize{0.21875in}{0in}\selectfont 24};
        \node[align=center] at (0.48in, -0.64in) {\fontsize{0.04in}{0in}\selectfont 105};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{frame}


\end{document}



SAM THE MAN!!!! Thanks dude

@ClydeKertzer sam the WOman :)
